# In ios 7, the Name of App is getting trimmed

Tags: ios7, icons

I have Example named "MyTCollection", When I am running that one in iOS 6 simulator, The AppName is displayed correctly(without Trimming), But when i run the same application in ios 7 simulator the app name is getting trimmed, it is displayed as "MyTCollec...", See screenshots below:

[image: ios 6 simulator screenshot]

ios 6 simulator screensshot

[image: ios 7 simulator screenshot]

ios 7  simulator screenshot

How does, i show "MyTCollection" name correctly(without trimming)?